# C# driver 2.0 Mongodb UpdateOneAsync

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

```
public class Student
{
    public long StudentId {get; set;}
    public string Fname {get; set;}
    public string Lname {get; set;}
    public List<ObjectId> CoursesList {get; set;}
    public int IQ {get;set;}
}

public class Courses
{
    [BsonId]
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public string CourseNumber{get; set;}
    public string CourseName{get; set;}
}
```

How do I add/append a courser Id to Course list(which may be null for the first time) of a Student object

PS: I know how to set a field using the below command. I am hoping it is on similar lines for the above problem

```
await StudentCollection.UpdateOneAsync(a => a.StudentId == studentId, Builders<Student>.Update.Set( a => a.IQ,90));
```

Comment: You mean something like this: Builders<Student>.Update.Set( a => a.CourseList, new []{ObjectId})

Comment: more like `Builders<Student>.Update.AddToSet( a => a.CourseList, newCourse.Id}) `
where newCourse is the newly course object created and I am trying to append its course Id into that course list of student object

Comment: Builders<Student>.Update.AddToSet( a => a.CourseList, new []{newCourse.Id})

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As you've already discovered, the C# code to use $addToSet is:

```
var filter = Builders<Student>.Filter.Eq(s => s.StudentId, studentId);
var update = Builders<Student>.Update.AddToSet(s => s.CoursesList, courseId);
var result = await collection.UpdateOneAsync(filter, update);
```

However, $addToSet is not going to work if the CourseList member has been stored in the collection as a null. The server requires that the existing value for $addToSet be an array (it can be an empty array).

The easiest solution is to just store an empty list for CoursesList instead of a null when there are no courses.

Comment: storing empty list to start with then using `Builders<Student>.Update.AddToSetEach(s => s.CoursesList, courseList);` worked for me. I think i didn't mention clearly in my question that i wanted add/append a new course list created.  Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me. When you define "List" like this, it will be empty and works with AddToSet/Push methods.

```
public List<ObjectId> CoursesList = new List<ObjectId>();
```

Answer (score 0):

The only case that you have to pay attention is when the array CourseList is null, in this case you have to use the code below [(see also here)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59914689/5409163):

```
var newListOfObject = new List<ObjectId>(){...}
await StudentCollection.UpdateOneAsync(a => a.StudentId == studentId, Builders<Student>.Update.Set( a => a.CoursesList, newListOfObject));
```

Otherwise you can use AddToSet or Push like explain in the other answers.